# the relationship between maximizing the likelihood and minimizing the cross-entropy

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, cross-entropy

There is a statement that maximizing the likelihood is equivalent to minimizing the cross-entropy.  Are there any proof for this statement?

Answer (score 21):

Here's a worked example in the case of iid binary data, each with a  success/failure recorded as $y_i \in \{0,1\}$.

For labels $y_i\in \{0,1\}$, the likelihood of some binary data under the Bernoulli model with parameters $\theta$ is
$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i=1|\theta)^{y_i}p(y_i=0|\theta)^{1-y_i}\\
$$
whereas the log-likelihood is
$$
\log\mathcal{L}(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\log p(y=1|\theta) + (1-y_i)\log p(y=0|\theta)
$$

And the binary cross-entropy is
$$
L(\theta) = -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\log p(y=1|\theta) + (1-y_i)\log p(y=0|\theta)
$$

Clearly, $ \log \mathcal{L}(\theta) = -nL(\theta) $.

We know that an optimal parameter vector $\theta^*$ is the same for both because we can observe that for any $\theta$ which is not optimal, we have $\frac{1}{n} L(\theta) > \frac{1}{n} L(\theta^*)$, which holds for any $\frac{1}{n} > 0$. (Remember, we want to *minimize cross-entropy*, so the optimal $\theta^*$ has the least $L(\theta^*)$.)

Likewise, we know that the optimal value $\theta^*$ is the same for $\log \mathcal{L}(\theta)$ and $ \mathcal{L}(\theta)$ because $\log(x)$ is a monotonic increasing function for $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, so we can write $\log \mathcal{L}(\theta) < \log\mathcal{L}(\theta^*)$. (Remember, we want to *maximize the likelihood*, so the optimal $\theta^*$ has the most $\mathcal{L}(\theta^*)$.)

Some sources omit the $\frac{1}{n}$ from the cross-entropy. Clearly, this only changes the *value* of $L(\theta)$, but not the *location* of the optima, so from an optimization perspective the distinction is not important. The negative sign, however, is obviously important since it is the difference between maximizing and minimizing!

---

Some more additional examples and more general result can be found in this related thread: [How to construct a cross-entropy loss for general regression targets?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378274/how-to-construct-a-cross-entropy-loss-for-general-regression-targets)

Comment: Is this specific for logistic regression or applicable in general such as to a deep/convolutional/recurrent neural network?

Comment: The definition of the loss/MLE function doesn't change -- as you can see, the likelihood is not tied to any particular functional form of the model -- so we can infer that cross-entropy loss and the binomial MLE are the same in both logistic regression and NNs. From an optimization perspective, the point of departure is that logistic regression is strongly **convex** under certain assumptions, while neural networks are generally **non-convex.** For example, you can permute the weights of a neural network and obtain the same loss, so there are many $\theta^*$ values with the same loss.

Comment: Same loss or same minimum loss?

Comment: Permutation equivalence of weights in an NN implies that if you have obtained some loss $L(\theta)$, then permuting the weights in a particular way will give the same loss value for the permuted vector $\theta$. So under these kinds of permutations, the losses are equal. This is true for minima corresponding to $\theta^*$ as well as the general case $\theta$ which do not minimize $L(\theta)$.

Comment: @Sycorax: Is it possible to exand this derivation to "soft" float labels [0,1]?

Comment: @gebbissimo It depends on what you mean. I'm not aware of a probability model which results in this loss function. On the other hand, this post explains why using this loss with non-binary targets in [0,1] are still useful models for training a neural network, without appealing to a probability model. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/394582/why-is-binary-cross-entropy-or-log-loss-used-in-autoencoders-for-non-binary-da

Comment: @Sycorax: Thanks for the super quick reply! Haven't found this thread before and will check it now