# What is the history of the "cross entropy" as a loss function for neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, references, loss-functions, supervised-learning, cross-entropy

There seems to be a gap in the literature as to why cross-entropy is used.

Older references on neural networks ("ANNs") always use the squared loss. For example, here is one from Chong and Zak "An Intro to Optimization 4th Ed",

[image]

Here is the one by Simon Haykin on "Kalman Filter and Neural Networks"
[image]

---

Somewhere along the way, cross-entropy became the dominant loss function that is used in many papers and almost all the "blog" type references on NN. Recall that the cross-entropy is often formulated as,

$$
CE(y, \hat y) = -\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N \sum\limits_{c = 1}^n y_n^c \cdot\log(\hat y_n^c)
$$
where $n$ is the $n$th data, $c$ is the $c$th class, and $y, \hat y$ denotes the set of targets and the predictions, respectively.

Where did the above function even came from (books/papers)? Was there some famous work that used cross entropy that popularized it over the squared loss? Is there a good reason to use CE as opposed to the squared loss (or the softmax loss associated with softmax/multiclass logistic regression)?

Comment: Do you require a neural network to have 1 or more hidden layers?

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica Not necessarily. One layer is good in my opinion.

Comment: What about 0 layers?

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica Fine by me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you agree that a logistic regression is a special case of a neural network, then the answer is D. R. Cox, who invented logistic regression.[1]

A neural network with zero hidden layers and a single sigmoid output and trained to maximize the binomial likelihood (equiv. minimize cross-entropy) is logistic regression.

Minimizing a binomial cross-entropy is equivalent to maximizing a particular likelihood: 
[the relationship between maximizing the likelihood and minimizing the cross-entropy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364216/the-relationship-between-maximizing-the-likelihood-and-minimizing-the-cross-entr)

[1] D. R. Cox.  "The Regression Analysis of Binary Sequences" *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological)*
Vol. 20, No. 2 (1958), pp. 215-242.